# Alternative to positive lookbehind when there are unknown number of spaces

Tags: java, regex

My `replacerRegex` is

```
("schedulingCancelModal": \{\s*? "title": ")(.+?)(?=")
```

The right value is getting picked up, i.e. `valueToBePicked`:
[image]

But how do I get `("schedulingCancelModal": \{\s*? "title": ")` not to be included in the result like positive lookbehind does?

My Java code so far:

```
Pattern replacerPattern = Pattern.compile(replacerRegex);
Matcher matcher = replacerPattern.matcher(value);

while (matcher.find()) {
    String valueToBePicked = matcher.group();
}
```

Comment: it looks like it's JSON data so why not just use a JSON library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply select `matcher.group(2)` which will give you the contents of the second capture group. For example:

```
    String replacerRegex = "(\"schedulingCancelModal\": \\{\\s*? \"title\": \")(.+?)(?=\")";
    String value = "\"valueToBePicked\": \"schedulingCancelModal\": {\n \"title\": \"Are you sure you want to leave scheduling?\", ... }";
    Pattern replacerPattern = Pattern.compile(replacerRegex);
    Matcher matcher = replacerPattern.matcher(value);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String valueToBePicked = matcher.group(2);
        System.out.println(valueToBePicked);
    }
```

Output:

```
Are you sure you want to leave scheduling?
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/SOSVVV16576)